# Add a filter like in SharePoint

Tags: sql-server, reportbuilder3.0

Is it possible to add a filter in "SQL Server Report Builder" like in SharePoint?

[image]

I am using SQL and want to filter it by "Sponsor" (Addidas, Fila, Nike etc)

It looks like this in my report builder:

```
ID    Name     Title  Sponsor
001   Addidas  Bosch  Jeffrey Unknown
```

My Problem is that when I choose more then one Customer in "Which Customer", it only shows me one Customer in table. But it should display the customers which I choose. I don't get it with the parameters I set. What did I wrong? By the way, I am just using one DataSet.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Andrew

Comment: Have you looked at SSRS filters, e.g. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239395(v=sql.105).aspx ? If this doesn't help, can you explain your requirements in a bit more detail?

Comment: Yeah, i did and I couldn't fin any answer in it. I updatet my post with my newest problem. I hope someone can help me and fix it. Tried the hole day yesterday and couldn't find any solution...

Comment: Are you using a stored procedure to generate the Dataset? Can you apply the filtering at the stored procedure level or does it have to be at the report/table level?

Comment: My QueryType is Text and I cannot choose Table, but Stored Procedure. Sorry, I am very new in this kind of stuff. What should I do? I am also using SQL Server 2012.